# Extracting a page from PDF document (using PDFBox)

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to break a PDF down into individual pages. Although it
functionally works, the pdf for each page ends up being almost the size of the original PDF (250MB). I've seen some references in deleting
annotations which might include links to other pages/resources. I've tried the below, but no luck. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

(Below code is in Kotlin). I've also tried using addPage vs. importPage,
since the later creates a deep copy. Same result.

```
doc.pages.forEachIndexed { idx: Int, p: PDPage ->
  val newDoc = PDDocument()
  val newPage = newDoc.importPage(p)
  newPage.annotations = null
  newPage.resources = null
  newDoc.save("/tmp/$idx.pdf")
  newDoc.close()
}
```

Comment: I figured this out.  I had to remove the PDThreadBead (setThreadBeads) on each page.  I went through the process of elimination here.  Page looks great.  I'm not sure what a thread bead is (can't seem to find it anywhere on the web) and class docs don't help.  Thanks!

Comment: Just found a reference to beads in the PDF specs.  It's a dictionary of items in an article.  For some reason, many of the pages in my pdf had what seems to be references to beads from all articles, thus the single page import, would import all articles (most of the document).  There were no apparent links in any of those pages to any articles/beads, but they must of been embedded by the tool used to create/export the pdf.

Comment: Yes... sometimes the structure points to another page, so that one is cloned as well. I'll think about what to do but not today, I'll keep your post from the mailing list. To see beads, open your PDF in PDFDebugger of the trunk (build yourself or get it from the snapshot directory). There is an option in the view menu and they'll appear in green (but only the ones of the page itself).